# Error in running .jar file

Tags: java, jar

I created a .jar file of my java game. The program ran well with a java compiler, but when I try to run the .jar file, it showed no result. I ran it again via CMD using:

```
java -jar PokemonGame.jar`
```

...it gave me an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.swing.ImageIcon.(init)(ImageIcon.java:167)
at MainFile.(init)(MainFile.java:25)
at MainFile.main(MainFile.java:86)
```

I traced the line numbers which I commented:

```
public class MainFile extends JPanel implements MouseListener{
    MainFile m;
    static JFrame mainWindow = new JFrame("POKEMON MEMORY GAME");
    static TimerFile timerPanel;
    static GridFile gridPanel;
    static LogsFile logsPanel;
    static ButtonMenuFile buttonMenuPanel;
    JPanel blockPanel;
    URL url;
    BufferedImage winlose;
    JPanel winlosePanel;
    //MainFile line 25
    ImageIcon gameBackground = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Assets\\Pokedex.png"));
    Image gameImage = gameBackground.getImage();
    GameSoundFile gameSound = new GameSoundFile();
    GameSoundFile screenSound = new GameSoundFile();

    //...some codes here

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        //MainFile line 86
        MainFile mainPanel = new MainFile();
        mainPanel.setMainPanel(mainPanel);          

        mainWindow.add(mainPanel);
        mainWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
        mainWindow.pack();
        mainWindow.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        mainWindow.setResizable(false);
        mainWindow.setVisible(true);

    }

    public MainFile(){
        //...MainFile codes here
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me the flaw here because it seems like a weird behavior that this program was able to run with a java compiler but not on the .jar execuatble file.

Comment: Seems like it can't get the image file.

Comment: `getClass().getResource("Assets\\Pokedex.png")`  is `null`  ?

Comment: But it was able to run using the java compiler. It showed no error during that runtime. Only when I converted it to a .jar file that it showed that error.

Comment: Are you sure the image is inside the jar, or in a relative path that can be reached from the jar?

Comment: The image is inside the assets folder. Is it necessary for all forms of documents(images, sounds) to be compiled inside the .jar file?

Comment: How did you create your .jar file?

Comment: jar cvfm Pokemon.jar manifest.txt *.class. Inside my manifest.txt is Main-Class: MainFile, with a newline character after that. I inputted the command at the exact directory as the mainfile.

Answer (score 0):

Pack `Pokedex.png` into jar at the top level:

```
jar uf PokemonGame.jar Pokedex.png
```

and reference it like that:

```
getClass().getResource("/Pokedex.png")
```

Comment: Like creating a package?

Comment: @Rapharlo Rather like creating or modifying a zip file.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Will try that and evaluate the result.

Comment: Question: jar uf PokemonGame.jar Pokedex.png, do I have to do it in the directory of the Assets folder or is it enough to be at the root folder?

Comment: @Rapharlo If you add it at root you can reference it as in the answer. If you add it in folder `Assets`, you will have to reference it `/Assets/Pokedex.png`.

Comment: Noted. Though odd enough, is it necessary for files(images, auido) to be compiled with the jar? Or can the jar file run with those files outside of the jar file? Reference on this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html

Comment: @Rapharlo Both ways will work. It just depends what you want. By using `getResource()` you are asking for resources from classpath. In your case, the only thing on classpath is your jar.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39424/discussion-between-rapharlo-and-grzegorz)

Answer (score 0):

Within JAR files, the windows directory separator character doesn't exist.  Use `/` to separate your directories, and assuming the file is there, it will be found.

Comment: Oh. So meaning I have to re-edit all my Assets//[filename] to Assets/?

Comment: More like Assets\\filename becomes Assets/filename